# Save developer specific local settings in Android project

Tags: android, git

I'm trying to store some developer specific settings locally (out of Git) in my project. For example, we have to work with different server configurations (dev, stage, live etc.). For now, the configurations are hardcoded in our Java code and each time one developer changes one configuration, he needs to undo it before pushing his code to the git (otherwise the configuration changes in every other developers' machine). Moving the file out git doesn't seem to be a good option, because each time the project is cloned the configuration file needs to be manually created (otherwise the project won't compile).

Ideally, I want something like a `local.properties` file in the project from where I can read the configurations in the code. Doing that in a plain Java project would be easy. But I can't read a file stored in my project in the same way like this, `FileReader in = new FileReader(new File("local.properties")))`, because Android doesn't seem to find the file in its path. It seems to me that it tries to read that file from the Android device's file system. I can't use the environment variable for the same reason. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: May be Assets folder?

Comment: As Sergey Petrov has mentioned,your best solution is to save all the configurations in the assets folder,otherwise you are left with hard-coding all the config in the java file and checking for something like if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)  in the runtime

Comment: Thanks, I would try that

Answer (score 1):

Do it in an XML file, just like you have `strings.xml`, create `strings_local.xml` or whatever you want to call it, and put the values there.  Add that file to your ignore file so it doesn't get checked in to source control because otherwise you'll have the same problem - devs have to undo their changes before checking in.  If you want to address the problem of not having values to work with when cloning the project, add an example file at the root of the project where Android won't pick it up as a resource file, and document it in the readme.